# Не настраивается Multiseat

Tags: linux

ДД. Не получается настроить Multiseat.
Параметры компьютера:

```
H/W path         Устройство  Класс     Описание
============================================================­==========
                                      system         10GB000URU (LENOVO_MT_10GB_BU_LENOVO_FM_ThinkCentre M600)
/0                                     bus            BRASWELL
/0/0                                   memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/28                                  memory         4GiB Системная память
/0/28/0                                memory         4GiB DIMM DDR3 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
/0/33                                  memory         112KiB L1 кэш
/0/34                                  memory         2MiB L2 кэш
/0/35                                  processor      Intel® Celeron® CPU  J3060  @ 1.60GHz
/0/100                                 bridge         Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register
/0/100/2                               display        Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller
/0/100/13                              storage        Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SATA Controller
/0/100/14                              bus            Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller
/0/100/14/0      usb1                  bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/1                          input          USB Keyboard
/0/100/14/0/2                          input          USB Optical Mouse
/0/100/14/0/5                          bus            USB 2.0 Hub
/0/100/14/0/5/1                        input          USB Optical Mouse
/0/100/14/0/5/2                        communication  Беспроводной интерфейс Bluetooth
/0/100/14/0/5/4                        input          USB Keyboard
/0/100/14/1      usb2                  bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1a                              generic        Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine
/0/100/1b                              multimedia     Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller
/0/100/1c                              bridge         Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #1
/0/100/1c/0      eno1                  network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
/0/100/1c.1                            bridge         Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #2
/0/100/1c.1/0    wlp2s0                network        Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth
/0/100/1f                              bridge         Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU
/0/100/1f.3                            bus            Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx SMBus Controller
/0/1             scsi0                 storage        
/0/1/0.0.0       /dev/sda              disk           500GB ST500LM021-1KJ15
/0/1/0.0.0/1     /dev/sda1             volume         465GiB Том EXT4
```

Сформировал файл xorg.conf:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
       Identifier     "Layout0"
       InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
       InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Screen     0   "Samsung_1" 0 0
EndSection
Section "ServerLayout"
       Identifier     "Layout1"
       Screen     1   "Samsung_2" RightOf "Samsung_1"
       InputDevice    "Keyboard1" "CoreKeyboard"
       InputDevice    "Mouse1" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
   Identifier     "Mouse0"
   Driver         "mouse"
   Option         "Protocol" "ImPS/2"
   Option         "Device" "/dev/input/mouse0"
   Option         "Protocol" "ExplorerPS/2"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
   Identifier     "Mouse1"
   Driver         "mouse"
   Option         "Protocol" "ImPS/2"
   Option         "Device" "/dev/input/mouse1"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
   Identifier     "Keyboard0"
   Driver         "evdev"
   Option         "Device" "/dev/input/by-path/usb-USB_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd"
   Option         "XkbRules" "xorg"
   Option         "XkbModel" "evdev"
   Option         "XkbLayout" "us"
   Option         "GrabDevice" "yes"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
   Identifier     "Keyboard1"
   Driver         "evdev"
   Option         "Device" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-USB_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd"
   Option         "XkbRules" "xorg"
   Option         "XkbModel" "evdev"
   Option         "XkbLayout" "us"
   Option         "GrabDevice" "yes"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
       Identifier   "Samsungblack"
EndSection
Section "Monitor"
       Identifier   "Samsungwhite"
       Option "DPMS" "true"
EndSection
Section "Device"
       Identifier  "Integrated out 1"
       Driver      "i915"
       BusID       "PCI:00:02:0"
       Option      "RenderAccel" "true"
       Screen       0
EndSection
Section "Device"
       Identifier  "Integrated out 2"
       Driver      "i915"
       BusID       "PCI:00:02:0"
       Option      "RenderAccel" "true"
       Screen       1
EndSection
Section "Screen"
       Identifier "Samsung_1"
       Device     "Integrated out 1"
       Monitor    "Samsungblack"
       DefaultDepth     24
       SubSection "Display"
               Depth     24
               Modes    "1920x1080" "1024x768" "832x624" "800x600" "720x400" "640x480"
       EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
       Identifier "Samsung_2"
       Device     "Integrated out 2"
       Monitor    "Samsungwhite"
       DefaultDepth     24
       SubSection "Display"
               Depth     24
               Modes     "1920x1080" "1024x768" "832x624" "800x600" "720x400" "640x480"
       EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Переписал файл /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf:

```
[SeatDefaults]
xserver-command=/usr/bin/X
user-session=xfce
greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
exit-on-failure=true
Seats=Seat:0 Seat:1
[Seat:0]
xserver-command=/usr/bin/X :0 -sharevts
autologin-guest=false
xserver-layout=Layout0
[Seat:1]
xserver-command=/usr/bin/X :1 -sharevts
autologin-guest=false
xserver-layout=Layout1
```

Не ничего не разделилось, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Во-первых, явно не хватает передачи конкретного `-layout` разным `X`'ам. Во-вторых, смотри логи иксов. В-третьих, вероятней всего так сделать не получится — каждый X-сервер захочет получить монопольный доступ к карте, так что придётся запускать один общий сервер на два экрана и в каждом запускать отдельный XEphyr (или какой-другой виртуальный `X`). А ещё `Screen` в `ServerLayout` выглядит не совсем верно...

Comment: @Fat-Zer 1. Не понял? Какая конкретика нужна? Где её посмотреть? 3. Не совсем понимаю как это, ведь нужно разделить тогда хотя бы мышей/клав чтобы работать на двух дисплеях? И подскажите какой нибудь виртуальный x-сервер. А в скрине не так? –

Comment: 1. про `-layout` — забудь. я не туда посмотрел... про остальное расписал в ответ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Основная проблема

На одной видеокарте *обычно* невозможно запустить два нативных независимых X сервера даже если у неё два выхода. AFAIK из правила есть несколько исключений, но они обычно являются ненадёжными хаками (например, ЕМНИП на старом блобе `nvidia` существовало состояние гонки и можно было запустить два сервера одновременно, чтобы они работали пости без артефактов). Также ЕМНИП старые радеоны на открытом драйвере представлялись системе как две независимые карты с разными BusId. Но всё это удел хаков и устаревшего/странного оборудования.

Короче говоря, **для полноценного multiseat'а нужно две независимые видеокарты.** А ещё немного удачи, чтобы драйвер был нормальный поддерживал одновременную работу с ними.

Есть альтернатива этому способу — запустить один X-сервер, растянутый на два монитора как обычно, а затем запустить два независимых виртуальных сервера на каждом мониторе. В качестве виртуального сервера сегодня обычно используют [`XEphyr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xephyr), как устаревший вариант также существует `XNest`. Вроде как в следующих релизах эту функциональность хотят встроить в штатный `X` со специальным драйвером, но сейчас не об этом.

Вариантов конфигурации и подводных камней с этим подходом несколько, в частности обычный `XEphyr` не поддерживает 3d ускорение. Вот одна из множества статей из гугла с вариантом конфига: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiseatOneCard

---

#### Несколько замечаний по конфигам.

**xorg.conf**

> ```
> Section "ServerLayout"
>        Identifier     "Layout1"
>        Screen     1   "Samsung_2" RightOf "Samsung_1"
>        ...
> ```

По всей видомости здесь должен быть `Screen 0 "Samsung_2" 0 0` или даже просто `Screen "Samsung_2"`. Номера экранов и положение экрана имеют смысл только при наличии нескольких записей `Screen` в одном `ServerLayout`'е. Скорей всего ни ничего не сломает, а X чихнёт в лог и переварит это нормально... но всё же...

**lightdm.conf**

> ```
> [SeatDefaults]
> ```

Не знаю откуда взялась такая секция — у себя в примерах конфиигов/доках ничего похожего я не нашёл.

---

#### Общие советы

- При ручной настройке X'ов, да и при любых проблемах с ними обычно черезвычайно полезно просматривать их логи, которые расположены в `/var/log/Xorg.*.log`.
- Также в данном случае что-то полезное может быть в логах lightDM'а.

Comment: Спасибо. Очень хороший ответ.  На текущий момент мне кое-что не понятно, буду разбираться.